# Interpolation Contours with Spline in ArcGIS 10

Tags: gis, spatial, arcgis

I have contours (about 5000 polylines) in shapefile and I need to interpolate those with Spline. But Spline function in ArcGIS 10 can only interpolate points, and my contours are polylines. I hope that anyone has a solution to my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [Topo to Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Topo_to_Raster/009z0000006s000000/) tool (in Spatial Analyst and/or 3D analyst extensions). I think there is also a "Feature to Point" tool available with an ArcInfo license.